# Proxy Java Web Service

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, proxy, weblogic

Recently I faced a need to create a proxy java web service running on weblogic server which consumes existing wcf services and then exposes their interfaces (that is the only way of 'hosting' wcf services on weblogic server I imagine is possible).

The sole role of this service would be just to act as a proxy (no additional functionality).

I need to be able to expose exactly the same interfaces in my proxy java web service as in my existing wcf services. The reason for this is that, I have an existing client application consuming my wcf services - new proxy java web service must be compatible, so that no changes are needed on client side.

What would be the best approach to achieve this? Is it possible? I am not experienced in java technologies and would really appreciate any tips.

So far, using JDeveloper I've managed to create web service data control based on existing wcf service's wsdl - is it possible to expose such data service through web service?

Comment: Maybe Apache CXF docs could have a solution? Check http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html and search "JAX-WS Proxy" it pherhaps helps you.

Comment: You should be able to do what you're asking. Use the exact same WSDL on the weblogic side and write code so that when the weblogic web service is invoked, it then calls the WCF services. The client would never know the difference unless I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: Thank you very much @better_use_mkstemp. It seems like the most logical way to go.

Comment: This essentially depends on why you want Weblogic servers to look like hosting this service. If you want same host for your other services as well, you could setup an Apache Web Server as a reverse proxy to route specific web service requests to WCF and all other requests to WebLogic servers. Instead, if all you want is only a proxy, again Apache Server with reverse proxy configuration might be a better solution than WebLogic server.

Comment: You can use JAX-WS Web Services for Oracle WebLogic Server. As it is mentioned, You can develop clients to invoke a WebLogic Web service using Java API for XML-based Web services (JAX-WS).  [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24964/client.htm) is the full documentation provided by Oracle. It is straightforward and easy to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is proxy functionality you are looking for you can use [this project](https://github.com/dsmiley/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet).

If you're using [maven](http://maven.apache.org/):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy</groupId>
        <artifactId>smiley-http-proxy-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you're not using maven you can probably just get the jar file from the Github repository.

Then in your web.xml you can point it to wherever your actual service is:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sampleProxy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy.ProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetUri</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:9200/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>log</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sampleProxy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sample/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

( And if the WSDL of your actual service has an endpoint defined in it to the actual service, just keep a local copy of the WSDL, change the endpoints and you're done. )

This is probably as time efficient as it gets, and requires next to no experience.

Comment: Nice, clean solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have almost answered your question.  "Proxy Web Service".  javaapp-->Java proxy webservice-->wcf webservice.  You can use the the same wsdl structure either end except that the IP in the endpoint address will only change.  To develop Proxy webservice in Java you can use Axis or Jax-WS.  **Quick Start Axis2** by **Deepal Jayasinghe** is good book for Axis2.  It explains about Service Client and Operational client importantly that you don't generally get in web references.  As for as JAX-WS you just compile the wsdl using wsdl2java and generate the stubs for client code.  For server code writing (where you will inturn call WCF) refer to `http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/`.  You may have to copy to $JDK_HOME\jre\lib\endorsed directory jaxb-api.jar and jaxws-api.jar files.